# pyqgis threading - Exception when using QgsTask.fromFunction

Tags: pyqgis, multithreading

I am trying to implement threading to some pyqgis code.

I have been trying to use **QgsTask.fromFunction**.

I have implemented code from [this article](http://www.opengis.ch/2018/06/22/threads-in-pyqgis3/) but it isn't working. I used the first of the three methods - basically verbatim, with minor changes to the structure to make it work in my plugin and to try to pin down the source of the error.

When I call testThreading I get the error

> Exception: <[my plugin] object at 0x00000267FA2E39B0>

Why?

```
def test_run(task, wait_time):

    from time import sleep
    import random

    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Started task {}'.format(task.description()),level=Qgis.Info)
    wait_time = wait_time / 100
    total = 0
    iterations = 0
    for i in range(101):
        sleep(wait_time)

        # use task.setProgress to report progress
        task.setProgress(i)

        total += random.randint(0, 100)
        iterations += 1

        # check task.isCanceled() to handle cancellation
        if task.isCanceled():
            test_stopped(task)
            return None

        # raise exceptions to abort task
        if random.randint(0, 500) == 42:
            raise Exception('bad value!')

    return {
      'total': total, 'iterations': iterations, 'task': task.description()
    }


  def test_stopped(task):
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('This does not happen',level=Qgis.Info)


  def test_completed(exception, result=None):

    if exception is None:
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('This does not happen',level=Qgis.Info)
    else:
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Exception: {}".format(exception),level=Qgis.Info)
        raise exception


  def testThreading(self):
    task1 = QgsTask.fromFunction(
      'waste cpu 1', self.test_run, on_finished=self.test_completed, wait_time=4)
    task2 = QgsTask.fromFunction(
      'waste cpu 2', self.test_run, on_finished=self.test_completed, wait_time=3)
    QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task1)
    QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task2)
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Getting here',level=Qgis.Info)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you are missing a few `self`, try to change `def test_run(task, wait_time):` to `def test_run(self, task, wait_time):` and `def test_completed(exception, result=None):` to `def test_completed(self, exception, result=None):`

I made a similar post trying to get clarity on the function `isCanceled()` here: [What happens when you press cancel on a QgsTask?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295004/what-happens-when-you-press-cancel-on-a-qgstask)