# QGIS QgsTask finished and completed never called

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I'm rewriting a plugin to use QgsTask with [this](https://www.opengis.ch/2018/06/22/threads-in-pyqgis3/) as my first guideline and the update mentioned in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/304801/23219) post as a possible solution for my problem. My task runs fine in the background, but

```
def finished(self, result):
```

and

```
def completed(self, exception, result=None):
```

are never called. Anybody any ideas?

*EDIT*: added more code below
*EDIT 2*: found out that if there is an error in the method *run* it then actually reaches *finished* before it gives an error.

main_plugin.py

```
# Import link to Qt and QGIS
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QMenu, QFileDialog
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar

# Import everything to create the plugin
from . import resources
from .plugin_dialog import PluginDialog
from .gdal_raster import Raster
from .task_raster import CreateRasterTask
from .task_raster import DoStuff

# Import everything to run the plugin
import sys
import os


class RasterPreparePlugin(object):
    def __init__(self, iface):
        # save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface

    def run(self):
        self.dlg = PluginDialog()
        self.dlg.show()

        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()

        if result:
            layer = combobox.currentLayer()
            path = self.dlg.ui.LineEditOutputLayer.text()

            raster = Raster(layer, path, VERSION)

            okay = DoStuff(raster, self.iface)
            okay.do_subclassed_tasks()
```

task_raster.py

```
from qgis.core import (
    QgsApplication,
    QgsTask,
    QgsMessageLog,
    Qgis,
    )

MESSAGE_CATEGORY = 'CreateRasterTask'

class CreateRasterTask(QgsTask):
    def __init__(self, description, raster):
        super(QgsTask, self).__init__(description, QgsTask.CanCancel)
        self.exception = None
        self.raster = raster

    def run(self):
        test = self.raster.task()

        return test

    def finished(self, result):
        if result:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                'Task "{name}" completed'.format(
                name=self.description()
                ),
            MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Success)
        else:
            if self.exception is None:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                    'Task "{name}" not successful but without '\
                    'exception (probably the task was manually '\
                    'canceled by the user)'.format(
                        name=self.description()),
                    MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Warning)
            else:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                    'Task "{name}" Exception: {exception}'.format(
                        name=self.description(),
                        exception=self.exception),
                    MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Critical)
                raise self.exception

    def cancel(self):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
            'Task "{name}" was canceled'.format(
                name=self.description()),
            MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Info)
        super().cancel()


class DoStuff:
    def __init__(self, raster, iface):
        self.raster = raster
        self.iface = iface
        self.task = CreateRasterTask('Test', self.raster)

    def do_subclassed_tasks(self):
        """Do tasks using QgsTask subclass. """
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.task)

    def stopped(self, task):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
            'Task "{name}" was canceled'.format(
                name=task.description()),
            self.MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Info)

    def completed(self, exception, result=None):
        if exception is None:
            if result is None:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                    'Completed with no exception and no result '\
                    '(probably manually canceled by the user)',
                    MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Warning)
            else:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                    'Task "{name}" finished'.format(
                        name=task.description()),
                    self.MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Info)
        else:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Exception: {}".format(exception),
                                    MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Critical)
            raise exception
```

gdal_raster.py

```
# Import link to QGIS
from qgis.core import (
    QgsPointXY,
    QgsExpressionContextScope,
    QgsExpressionContextUtils,
    QgsMessageLog,
    Qgis,
    )

# Import everything to run the plugin
import osgeo.gdal as gdal
import osgeo.osr as osr
import numpy as np
import datetime
import math


class Raster(object):
    def __init__(self, layer, path, version):
        self.layer = layer
        self.path = path
        self.version = version

    def task(self):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Debug 5', 'MESSAGE_CATEGORY', Qgis.Success)
        try:
            # do stuff
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

Comment: Maybe you can share a little bit more of your code to help us understand what could be wrong...

Comment: @YoLecomte of course. Removed non essential stuff, but added the three files I use.

Comment: In your example `DoStuff.do_subclassed_tasks` is never called. So your task is not executed (or I miss something).

Comment: It is called, missed to copy that line. So the method 'run' is executed, but it never triggers the method 'finished'.

Comment: @YoLecomte any ideas? I added some extra information I found.

Comment: Unfortunaly I have no idea... I don't have a lot of experience with QgsTask... I usually implements my own class to run in the background.You can find some example in this plug-in that I wrote : https://github.com/Paprika-plugins/PaPRIKa/blob/master/worker.py

Comment: @Matthieu did you ever find a solution for this? I am encountering the same problem - `finished` is never called except when I throw an exception. I'm using a task function instead of a task class, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: @James no, unfortunately not.

Comment: @Matthieu I've tried both the task functions and task classes. I ended up using a signal at the end of the run function to send information back to the main thread

Comment: @Tim can you share some code?

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same trouble with QgsTask in the past. The issue (as far as I can work out) seems to be when tasks are run from a plugin. I've tried both tasks from a function and subclassed tasks from the python console and they both called the finished function upon completion.

As a workaround for subclassed tasks in a plugin I was using `pyqtSignal` in the tasks class which I would subscribe to in the main thread. I added the `myObjectSignal = pyqtSignal(object)` at the start of class before its initialized. I'm using an object but you could return any type eg `myListSignal = pyqtSignal(list)`

```
class SubclassedTask(QgsTask):

    myObjectSignal = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, argument1):
        super().__init__(_description, QgsTask.CanCancel)
        self.argument1 = argument1
        self.result = None
```

In the run method of the class I would emit the signal if it reached the end

```
     def run(self):
         Caluclate the result...
         self.myObjectSignal.emit(self.result)
         return True
```

In the main thread I would create the class instance then subscribe to the signal in it before adding it to the task manager. This would connect to a function in the main thread that could do something with the information being returned.

```
        newTask = SubclassedTask(argument1)
        newTask.myObjectSignal.connect(self.completeTaskProcessing)
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(newTask)
```

The handling method in the main thread would look like this

```
     def completeTaskProcessing(self,taskResult):

         print(taskResult)
```

I probably should have been disconnecting from the signal upon completion but I never added it and it seems to work currently so I'm not looking to touch it.