# QgsTask: finished-function isn't executed

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, multithreading

I am writing a plugin for QGIS. I created a task by subclassing `QgsTask`, it's basically copied from the PyQGIS Cookbook and looks like this:

```py
import json
import urllib.request

from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import NULL
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeature, QgsVectorLayer, QgsTask

from .utils import point2wgs84, message_bar, log_message, LayerNotFoundError


class GeocodeTask(QgsTask):
    def __init__(self, only_missing: bool, config, finished_callback):
        if only_missing:
            super().__init__('Fehlende Adressen bestimmen')
        else:
            super().__init__('Alle Adressen bestimmen')

        self.finished_callback = finished_callback
        self.exception = None
        self.only_missing = only_missing
        self.config = config

        # Counters for progress display
        self.total_features = 0
        self.finished_features = 0
        self.failed_features = 0

        # DEBUG
        self.debug = True

    def finished(self, result):
        log_message('Aufgabe abgeschlossen', 'info')
        if result:
            log_message('Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde erfolgreich beendet. Es wurden {} Adressen nicht gefunden'.format(
                self.description, str(self.failed_features)), 'success')
            message_bar('Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde erfolgreich beendet. Es wurden {} Adressen nicht gefunden'.format(
                self.description, str(self.failed_features)), 'success')
        else:
            if self.exception is None:
                log_message(
                    'Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde nicht erfolgreich, aber ohne Fehlermeldung beendet.\n\
                    (Wahrscheinlich vom Benutzer abgebrochen)'.format(
                        self.description), 'warning')
                message_bar('Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde wahrscheinlich vom Benutzer abgebrochen.'.format(self.description),
                            'warning')

            else:
                log_message(
                    'Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde mit einem Fehler beendet: {}'.format(self.description, self.exception),
                    'critical')
                message_bar(
                    'Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde mit einem Fehler beendet: {}'.format(self.description, self.exception),
                    'critical')
                raise self.exception
        self.finished_callback()

    def geocode_feature(self, layer: QgsVectorLayer, feature: QgsFeature):
        if self.only_missing:
            # If the address is already set, continue with the next one
            if feature['address'] != NULL:
                return True

        # Get the coordinates of the point
        coord = feature.geometry().asPoint()
        coord_converted = point2wgs84(coord)
        lat = coord_converted[1]
        lon = coord_converted[0]

        # Send the coordinates to the osm api
        url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat={lat}&lon={lon}'.format(lon=lon, lat=lat)
        con = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        res = con.read().decode('utf-8')
        con.close()
        results = json.loads(res)

        try:
            # If road, house number, postcode and town is set
            result = results['address']['road'] + ' ' + str(results['address']['house_number']) + ', ' + \
                     results['address']['postcode'] + ' ' + results['address']['town']
        except KeyError:
            try:
                # If road, postcode and town is set, but the house number not
                result = results['address']['road'] + ', ' + results['address']['postcode'] + ' ' + results['address'][
                    'town']
            except KeyError:
                # If no address is found
                result = NULL

        # Save the address to the feature
        feature['address'] = result
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
        if result is NULL:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def geocode_layer(self, layer: QgsVectorLayer):
        # DEBUG
        max_features = self.finished_features + 20

        layer.startEditing()
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            # Look if the task was cancelled
            if self.isCanceled():
                break

            # If geocode_feature() is true, an address was set or already found
            if not self.geocode_feature(layer, feature):
                self.failed_features += 1
            self.finished_features += 1

            # Display progress
            self.setProgress(self.finished_features / self.total_features * 100)

            # DEBUG
            if self.debug and self.finished_features > max_features:
                break
        layer.commitChanges()

    def run(self):
        try:
            try:
                layer_hydranten: QgsVectorLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(self.config.layers.hydranten)[0]
                layer_brunnen: QgsVectorLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(self.config.layers.brunnen)[0]
            except IndexError:
                message_bar('Ein Layer konnte nicht gefunden werden. Bitte überprüfen Sie die Einstellungen.',
                            level='critical')
                self.exception = LayerNotFoundError()
                return False

            if self.debug:
                self.total_features = 40
            else:
                self.total_features += layer_brunnen.featureCount()
                self.total_features += layer_hydranten.featureCount()

            self.geocode_layer(layer_brunnen)
            # Look if the task was cancelled
            if self.isCanceled():
                return False

            self.geocode_layer(layer_hydranten)
            # Look if the task was cancelled
            if self.isCanceled():
                return False
            return True
        except Exception as ex:
            self.exception = ex
            return False
```

The task runs great, but when it is finished, only the built-in QGIS message comes up that the task has been completed. What I wrote in the `finished()`-function is not executed at all. I start the task by pressing a menu entry that executes this piece of code:

```py
self.task_running = True
task = GeocodeTask(False, self.config, self.set_task_running_false)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)
message_bar('Task gestartet: Alle Adressen bestimmen')
```

And this is my QGIS version:

```
QGIS-Version                        3.20.0-Odense
QGIS-Codeversion                    decaadbb31
Qt-Version                          5.15.2
Python-Version                      3.9.5
GDAL-Version                        3.3.1
PROJ-Version                        8.1.0
EPSG-Registraturdatenbankversion    v10.027 (2021-06-17)
GEOS-Version                        3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
SQLite-Version                      3.35.2
PDAL-Versio                         2.3.0
PostgreSQL-Client-Version           13.0
SpatiaLite-Version                  5.0.1
QWT-Version                         6.1.3
QScintilla2-Version                 2.11.5
OS-Version                          Windows 10 Version 2009

Active Python-Plugins:              firstaid, GeoCoding, loeschwasser, pluginbuilder3, plugin_reloader, db_manager, processing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the same question on the right sidebar. ([QGIS QgsTaks finished and completed never called](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357489/qgis-qgstaks-finished-and-completed-never-called?rq=1))

It says that QGIS tasks in plugins are broken, because the `finished()` and `completed()` functions are never executed, but there is a way to achieve the same with Qt Signals.

I tried this and it worked:
I added a `pyqtSignal` to my task class:

```py
class GeocodeTask(QgsTask):
    finished_signal = pyqtSignal(bool, str, int, object)

    def __init__(self, only_missing: bool, config):
        if only_missing:
            super().__init__('Fehlende Adressen bestimmen', QgsTask.CanCancel)
        else:
            super().__init__('Alle Adressen bestimmen', QgsTask.CanCancel)

        self.exception = None
        self.only_missing = only_missing
        self.config = config

        # Counters for progress display
        self.total_features = 0
        self.finished_features = 0
        self.failed_features = 0
```

Then i added every time, my run function could exit, this lines:

```py
self.finished_signal.emit(False, self.description(), self.failed_features, self.exception)
return False
```

The first parameter shows if the task completed successfully, the second and third parameters are needed for a message and the last parameter contains an exception (if aviable) to trow it in the main thread.

As last, I moved the finished function to the main plugin class and registered it to the signal in the task:

```py
    def geocode_finished(self, state: bool, description: str, failed_features: int, exception: object):
        if state:
            message_bar('Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde erfolgreich beendet. Es wurden {} Adressen nicht gefunden'.format(
                description, str(failed_features)), level='success')
        else:
            if exception is None:
                log_message(
                    'Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde nicht erfolgreich, aber ohne Fehlermeldung beendet.\n\
                    (Wahrscheinlich vom Benutzer abgebrochen)'.format(
                        description), level='warning')
                message_bar(
                    'Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde wahrscheinlich vom Benutzer abgebrochen.'.format(description),
                    level='warning')
            else:
                message_bar(
                    'Die Aufgabe "{}" wurde mit einem Fehler beendet: {}'.format(description, exception),
                    level='critical')
                raise exception
        self.task_running = False
# ...
    def geocode_all(self):
        self.task_running = True
        task = GeocodeTask(False, self.config)
        task.finished_signal.connect(self.geocode_finished)
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)
        message_bar('Task gestartet: Alle Adressen bestimmen', level='info')
```